# Search through xml

Tags: c#, xml

For the program I am making it is built off of this XML file and I really need help with some logic.

Before I go any further, the xml file has the structure which looks like this:

```
<applications>
  <app num="1" desc="changed">
    <appname>test</appname>
    <version>V 30</version>
    <srcpath>c:\</srcpath>
    <dstpath>c:\</dstpath>
  </app>
  <app num="2" desc="changed">
    <appname>testing 123</appname>
    <version>V 11</version>
    <srcpath>C:\Users\testing\src</srcpath>
    <dstpath>C:\Users\\testing\dst</dstpath>
  </app>
</applications>
```

With that in mind, the app I am creating is based off of this xml file. 
I'll give you a little background on the program. I have a form with drop down data windows which display the app name, version, description, source path, and destination path.

The user is able to modify these paths and all of the information associated with it - except "num". I want to be able to search through the xml file without having to search the "appname" or any of the changeable components (appname, version, desc, srcpath, and dstpath are all changeable)

The problem I am having is when the user selects to modify, a new window pops up which retrieves the information about the paths. When modify is clicked the logic at the moment is to search by the appname and then get the "num" through that. HOWEVER the problem with this method is that the appname can be the same as other app names and then once it finds an appname that matches, it proceeds to display the info. however it can be the wrong info. How do I go about retrieving the "num" in order to display the correct info?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want to say "find the instance with this specific `num` value", or do you want to find all the instances and then obtain their num so you can check it yourself? And when you say "path", do you mean XPath or something else?

Comment: @keshlam When I say path I mean as in a path such as "c:\users\documents" type of path that the user enters in. and I want to find one instance where the num matches up with whatever current num the user has selected

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, `num` plays the role of a unique identifier. If the identifier is truly unique, I suggest using a [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To do so, create a class that will represent an item from your xml:

```
class AppData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    // Other properties here
}
```

When you start your app, load the data from xml:

```
public Dictionary<int, AppData> LoadData(string xmlPath)
{
    return XDocument.Load(xmlPath)
        .Descendants("app")
        .Select(e => new AppData
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Attribute("num").Value),
            Name = e.Descendants("appname").Single().Value
        })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
}
```

And when the user wants to change a specific item, load it from the dictionary:

```
var dataItem = dictionary[id];
using(var form = new ChangeItemForm(dataItem))
{
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Of course, don't forget to save the dictionary data back to the file when finished.

Comment: Why would saving the dictionary data back to the file be needed?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to get is the node from the XML file depending on the attribute "num" value...
This might be what you're looking for:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("filePath");
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//[@num='YOUR_VALUE']");
XmlNode node = nodeList[0];
```

And then do whatever you want with this node

Answer (score 0):

There are tool to work with xml. Kerim suggested DOM xml, which I wouldn't recommend to work with, in C#.

Instead, I suggest you use LINQ to XML... 
[How to work with LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

good luck

UPDATE:
RePierre unswer is better than mine. I'm leaving it here for the link on LINQ to XML.